# To delay JavaScript function call using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    function sample() {
       alert("This is sample function");
    }
 
    $("#button").click(function(){
        t = setTimeout("sample()",2000);
    });
        
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Call sample function with delay">
```

Once I click the button, `sample()` function is not called with a delay of 2 seconds. I don't know what's wrong.

How to call JavaScript function using `setTimeout()` via jQuery?

Comment: You should have seen something like *sample is not defined* on the console.

Comment: @Felix Kling, If you were mentioning to me, I could see a sample defined.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Since you declare `sample` inside the anonymous function you pass to `ready`, it is scoped to that function.

You then pass a *string* to `setTimeout` which is `eval`ed after 2 seconds. This takes place outside the current scope, so it can't find the function.

**Only pass *functions* to `setTimeout`**, using eval is inefficient and hard to debug.

```
setTimeout(sample,2000)
```

Comment: ...or wrap to your liking: `setTimeout( function() { myBarFunction('whatever','parameter', 123)}, 2000 );

Answer (score 36):

```
function sample() {
    alert("This is sample function");
}

$(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        setTimeout(sample, 2000);
    });

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/nrqnY/).

If you want to encapsulate `sample()` there, wrap the whole thing in a self invoking function `(function() { ... })()`.

Answer (score 21):

Very easy, just call the function within a specific amount of milliseconds using [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

```
setTimeout(myFunction, 2000)

function myFunction() {
    alert('Was called after 2 seconds');
}
```

Or you can even initiate the function inside the timeout, like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Was called after 2 seconds');
}, 2000)
```