# php/jquery search box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search, search-engine

I'm trying to implement a search box using php and jquery (the seach results are coming from a database). What I want to do is that as the user type into the search box, a query is made to find the data that contains the keyword the user entered into the search box. The problem I'm having is that I have something like this:

```
$("#my_search_box").keyup(function(){

    retrieve_results($(this).val());    

});
```

The problem with doing this is that, the function retrieve_results() is called every time the user is done typing (of course, cause that's what the keyup is there for). Therefore, this can get very slow because if the user type a word that has like 10 characters, the retrieve_results() function gets called 10 times in a row. Also, I should mention that inside my retrieve_results() function, I'm doing an Ajax request using jQuery $.ajax to get the results. So my question is the following:

How do I make it so that my function retrieve_results() doesn't get executed everytime the user stops typing (every time the key is up). I want to keep that functionality though, I don't want the user to click on a "Search" button or something. I just would like my retrieve_results() function to get called only once when the user is done entering all the keywords (not everytime the user enters a letter or something)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you only want the search to fire for the very last character the user types. The best way to do this is to give him enough time to continually type, and if he pauses (even to think), run the search.
Using `setTimeout` by itself won't work because even that would fire multiple times. You have to clear the timeout by using `clearTimeout`.

You can use the following to achieve the desired effect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeout,
        $search_box = $('#my_search_box');

    $search_box.keyup(function() {
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }

        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            search();
        }, 1000);
    });

    function search() {
        var search_txt = $search_box.val();
    }
});
```

Here's what's happening:
We assign the `setTimeout` timer to a variable, which must be declared above your keyup function, and check that variable each time `keyup` fires. If there's an existing `setTimeout` in progress, clear it out so that it won't fire the `search()` function and create a new timer set to wait a specified number of milliseconds (1000 in my example).

See the following JSFiddle for demo: http://jsfiddle.net/highwayoflife/WE4Fr/

Comment: Thanks very much, you're the man, but question, why do I have to clear the timer every time?

Comment: @user765368 We only clear the timeout if there is an existing "timeout" function running. If we didn't clear this timeout, your search would fire for each key press, only delaying by 1000 milliseconds. You can try it... in the jsfiddle, remove the `if (timeout) ... ` code and run the script. You'll notice how every key press will fire the search function after 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

You could start a timmer...let`s say...after first key...if the interval is greater than 2 sec (between keys) do a search else wait
http://api.jquery.com/delay/

**EXAMPLE**(from [To delay JavaScript function call using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322344/to-delay-javascript-function-call-using-jquery)):

```
  $("#button").bind("sample",function() {
      sample();
    });

    $("#button").click(function(){
      $(this).delay(2000).trigger("sample");
    });
```

Didn't have time to test with **delay**

ALTERNATIVE (tested)
done in 3 min it`s late (2:12 AM my local time)

```
$("#my_search_box").keyup(function(){
            setTimeout(search, 30000);
});
function search(){
        alert('ok');
}
```

Comment: What if my function takes parameters, how do I pass those parameters inside my setTimeout function?

Comment: But still, my function is called the number of times the keyup has executed. All this is doing is delaying the execution of my function, like I said above, I want my function retrieve_results() to be called only ONCE

Comment: All this does is delay the searching for 30000ms, but it will still fire for every keystroke hit. e.g.: if the user typed in `chrysanthemum`, this script will wait 30000ms and then fire off `search()` 13 times.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using either the delay method in jQuery or the setTimeout() function in JavaScript where the interval would be reset to the original interval every time the keyup method executes. [Here is a brief explanation](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) of the setTimeout() method and several other timer methods found in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Something Like this should do it. You create a global variable to store the query, and another one to know if enough time has passed for a new call to retrieve_results. You update the searchQuery every keyup, but only do the retrieve_results after the time you want. I hope it helps you.

```
    searchQuery="";
    timeIsUp=true;

    $("#my_search_box").keyup(function(){

      searchQuery=$(this).val();

      if(timeIsUp){
        timeIsUp=false;
        setTimeOut("retrieve_results(searchQuery); timeIsUp=true",500); 
      }

    });
```

Comment: I hope this is not unpolite, I cannot comment in the first answer and I think you can do it better. You don't need to call clear time out, like in the first answer, you just need to don't create a new setTimeOut if another one is running and store the searchQuery on a variable so that the last change is always the one that is looked for. It's more efficient than create and destroy a lot of timers.

Comment: If you did not use clear timeout and just didn't fire, the search is still going to fire even if the user isn't done typing yet. So let's say it takes him 5 seconds to type in a query, instead of waiting until he's done, the search will have fired 10 times (500ms) or 5 times with 1000ms wait. Using clearTimeout, the search will wait to fire when the user is done typing for 1000ms. This is lighter on servers.

Comment: True, sorry. That would be lighter on the server, that's true.