# Run Function After Delay

Tags: jquery

I have the below global jQuery function stored, but on page load, I want to execute it after a 1000 delay. Is there something wrong with my syntax? I know the delay always goes before the function. It is not responding.

Global function:

```
function showpanel() {     
       $(".navigation").hide();
       $(".page").children(".panel").fadeIn(1000);
    ;}
```

Executing function:

```
parallax.about.onload=function(){
    $('#about').delay(3000).showpanel();
};
```

Comment: This is what you are looking for man:) hope this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322344/to-delay-javascript-function-call-using-jquery

Comment: The first clear problem is you are attempting to call showpanel as a method of another object (in this case, the jQuery object returned by the delay() call).  But you've declared showpanel as a simple, directly-accessible function, rather than a method of any object.  JavaScript doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // place this within dom ready function
  function showpanel() {     
    $(".navigation").hide();
    $(".page").children(".panel").fadeIn(1000);
 }

 // use setTimeout() to execute
 setTimeout(showpanel, 1000)

});
```

For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322344/to-delay-javascript-function-call-using-jquery)

Answer (score 53):

I searched and found the solution in the following URL is **better**.

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/call-a-function-after-some-time-in-jquery.php

It worth to try.

It adds your given function to the queue of functions to be executed on the matched element which is currently ***this***.

```
 $(this).delay(1000).queue(function() {

     // your Code | Function here
     
     $(this).dequeue();
  
  });
```

and then execute the next function on the queue for the matched element(s) which is currently ***this*** again.

## -- EDIT [ POSSIBLE EXPLANATION FOR THE *DEQUEUE* COMMAND ]

*Take a look at the command*

We command the jQuery engine to add a function in internal queue and then after a specific amount of time we command it to call that function, **BUT** so far we never told it to dequeue it from engine. Right?! And then after every thing is done we are dequeue it from jQuery engine manually. I hope the explanation could help.

Comment: Can you summarize the solution and explain how it works?  Just linking to a solution isn't ideal because that link may stop working at some point in the future...

Comment: @devlincarnate I updated the post.Read it and see it is simple to understand or not.Hope it be useful.

Comment: This doesn't explain what queue does or why dequeue is necessary.  What purpose does dequeue server; I wouldn't expect t'he function to execute more than once, so why dequeue it?

Comment: `$('#main > ul').delay(100).queue(function () { $(this).attr('data-uk-grid', 'masonry: true; parallax: 150;').dequeue() });
  $('#main > ul').delay(1).queue(function () { $(this).removeClass('uk-grid uk-flex-top uk-flex-wrap-top').dequeue() });`

Comment: still no explanation on why the dequeue is needed?

Comment: @Niklas I updated the post. please take a look at it.

Answer (score 38):

You can add timeout function in jQuery (Show alert after 3 seconds):

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    setTimeout(function() {
     alert("Hello");
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just  useful to understand how you can make **delay** using JQuery `delay` function.

Imagine you have an alert and you want to set the alert text then show the alert and after a few seconds hide it.

Here is the simple solution:

```
$(".alert-element").html("I'm the alert text").fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
```

---

**It is completely simple:**

1. `.html()` will change the text of `.alert-element`
2. `.fadeIn(500)` will fade in after 500 milliseconds
3. JQuery `delay(5000)` function will make 5000 milliseconds of delay before calling next function
4. `.fadeOut(1000)` at the end of the statement will fade out the `.alert-element`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jQuery’s [delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) method to set the delay time interval.

**HTML code:**

```
  <div class="box"></div>
```

**JQuery code:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".show-box").click(function(){
      $(this).text('loading...').delay(1000).queue(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        showBox(); 
        $(this).dequeue();
      });        
    });
  });
```

You can see an example here: [How to Call a Function After Some Time in jQuery](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-call-a-function-after-some-time-in-jquery/)