# Wait to call a method from the Action page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I'm kinda new to the JSP world.
I have this web application that calls the page below, the `result.jsp` page.
This page is called after a submit on a form, and the action class generates an image from the `createImage` method, called by a `dispatchParam`.

The actual code part is this:

```
<div id="container_imagem_resultado">
    <p>
        <img src="<%=pathBase%>access.do?dispatchParam=createImage&time="new Date().getTime();>
</div>
```

I need to create some trigger so the page waits for 1s before calling the `img` tag.

How can I do it?
is there a way to dinamically insert into the HTML response page the tag after that 1s wait? Would adding `<%Thread.sleep(1000);%>` just before the `img` tag work?

Comment: Of course not, the `Thread.sleep` runs on the *server* side. Use a JS timeout and set the source attribute when it fires.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the idea. But houw could I make it happen in the page? I've seen some ```timeout``` examples on the internet, but couldn't figur out what to do in my case.

Comment: By writing javascript-I'm not sure what else to tell you, are you familiar with JavaScript?

Comment: Not quite. I've seen some functions but I don't really understand it.
I've seen lots of examples, all of them calling a timeout triggered by a button or something, but I need mine to trigger the moment the page loads.

Comment: Sound like it is about time to learn :-)

Comment: Yeah. I accidentally pressed "enter" while writing my answer above, I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a delay in Java (server-side) on the page, even in a scriptlet, will only result in a delay in sending the page to the client's browser, which results in either a long pause before they receive the page, or (in some cases) a half-loaded page with an odd delay until the rest is loaded.

To delay the loading of something on the client-side, the best answer is to use Javascript. Given that you've tagged the question [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), I'm going to assume that jQuery is an available option for you.

For that purpose, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10860174/410342) gives a reasonable example of what to do here:

```
// jQuery construct; calls this function after the page is ready.
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Create the function which loads the image.
    function showImage() {
        // Gets a handle for the container div, and replaces its HTML contents.
        // Not the most elegant, but it works.
        $("#container_imagem_resultado").html('<p><img src="<%=pathBase%>access.do?dispatchParam=createImage&time=' + new Date().getTime()  + '" /></p>');
    }

    // Schedule it after 1 second (1000ms).
    setTimeout(showImage, 1000);
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="container_imagem_resultado">
    <p>
        <!-- TODO placeholder -->
    </p>
</div>
```

As a side note, isn't 1 second a little long for a loading delay? Unless you intend for there to be a noticeable lag in the image loading, or there's another reason for loading the image after 1 second, you should make it a lot lower, otherwise it might come across as a broken window.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try it.

EDIT: The lag is intended, but thanks to the tip too.