# Fullpage.js. Adding a scroll delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I have a div "box" which fades gradually using ".fp-viewing" as an anchor to start the transition effect when a user scrolls to the next page. The thing is the page starts scrolling when .fp-viewing is triggered and scrolls box out of view before the finish of the animation.

How can I delay the start of the scrolling when .fp-viewing is triggered till box has done its animation in 4s?

```
.box{
  transition: all 4s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 4s ease-out;
}

.fp-viewing-2 .box{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can play with the option fullpage.js provides to [cancel a movement before it takes place](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#cancelling-the-scroll-before-it-takes-place).

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/alvarotrigo/o5ak4mgd/5/)

```
var delay = 2000; //milliseconds
var timeoutId;
var animationIsFinished = false;

new fullpage('#fullpage', {
      sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction){
        var curTime = new Date().getTime();

        //animating my element
        $('#element').addClass('animate');

        clearTimeout(timeoutId);

        timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
            animationIsFinished = true;

            fullpage_api.moveTo(destination.index + 1);
        }, delay);

        return animationIsFinished;
    },
});
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion and see how it works out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: your code working thanks for that, but its not what i wanted. I guess its my fault for not clearly explaining what I need. I watched your video "Create css3 animations between sections with fullpage.js", thats how I developed the css animations code I pasted in my first comment.

Comment: My css animation is triggered when ".fp-viewing" changes and .fp-viewing is triggered when a user scrolls on mouse to new section. The code you pasted delays the triggering of .fp-viewing. thats not what i need.

I need .fp-viewing to be triggered first, then delayed for like 5s before scrolling to the next section starts, because my css animation is triggered by .fp-viewing and it needs to finish its animation before scrolling to the next section.

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing this the right way. maybe i need a different trigger for my animations other than .fp-viewing. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are not doing it the right way. You should trigger your animation in the `onLeave callback` outside the timeout function. Just add a class to your element there to trigger it. You have think what's the best for your purpose and the class `fp-viewing` is not in this case.

Comment: You can always invite to a coffee by donating to the fullpage.js project! :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
#fullpage {
    transition-delay: 1s !important;
}
```

or modify function addAnimation 
in fullpage.js

Comment: So simple and it works for me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for me work this variant:

```
$(elem).fullpage({ 
/// opttions, 
onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction){ 
if(animationIsFinished === false){ 
// do some code 
} 
clearTimeout(timeoutId); 
timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){ 
animationIsFinished = true;
 $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(destination); 
   setTimeout(() => { 
     animationIsFinished = false; 
   }, 200); 
}, 600); 
return animationIsFinished;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is cheap and easy, but I just wrap the Full Page function I need in custom function wrapper, then use `settimeout` (a la [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860171/run-function-after-delay/41300075)) to fire it when I'm ready.

```
function slideWithDelay() {
    fullpage_api.moveSlideRight();
}

// Change slide on select
$('select').on('change',function(){
    setTimeout(slideWithDelay, 500);
})
```