# How to animate elements before scroll-events take place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, fullpage.js

need some help with *Fullpage.js*, but this question can also be seen more generally.

how can I insert an animation **before** the scroll event takes place? If you have a solution without *Fullpage.js* you are welcome, too. I read about blocking a scroll/click event altogether somewhere and attribute own functions and methods but that is not what I am searching for, since I am not capable of rewriting any event from the *Fullpage.js* script. Just want to stick the animation in between the scroll input and the actual scrolling.

Practical example: I scroll, the elements fade out, then the page scrolls to the next section.

Live example: http://www.basicagency.com/yir/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176677/fullpage-js-adding-a-scroll-delay/36182162#36182162). Check [the example I gave](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36182162/1081396)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [onLeave](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction) callback.

> This callback is fired once the user leaves a section, in the transition to the new section. Returning false will cancel the move before it takes place.

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
    alert('onLeave fired');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">section</div>
  <div class="section">section</div>
  <div class="section">section</div>
  <div class="section">section</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will check that out!

Comment: Okay, I checked that out and understood it. Now it's time to combine it with let's say a jQuery Animation like fade out. How do make it halt the scroll animation, then fire the fade animation and then get go with the scroll animation?

`code`
$('#fullpage').fullpage({

      onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
       if(direction=='down') {
         $( "h1" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
       }
      }
   });

`code`

Comment: Thanks, now I got it!