# Fullpage.js scroll delay using callbacks

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I'm using FullPage.js and I have to animated the background before going to the next section ( up and down ). So I wonder how I could use the fullpage callbacks to create a delay before scrolling.

I read already this topic [Fullpage.js. Adding a scroll delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176677/fullpage-js-adding-a-scroll-delay)

It's close to what I'm looking for but I can find how I can transform it to match with my request.

Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: What exactly is what you can not reproduce? In that example you can see how to call any code before moving to the next section.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, here is an example : https://fullpage-test-539204.webflow.io/
I would like to add 1 seconds delay when index 1 goes to index 2 and same when index 1 goes to index 0 so the background has time to cover the entire window before scrolling up. Does it help? Thanks

Comment: Not really. Can you please specify in what way the solution you linked is not providing you with the solution you need?

Comment: Because it adds a 2s delay before scrolling and it's what I'm looking for but just every time you go to the index 1 to the index 0