# fullpage.js Add delay to beforeLeave event until video is ready to play

Tags: javascript, function, delay, fullpage.js

i'am looking for a way to wait with the scroll until the video has been preloaded and is ready to play. I have already seen [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176677/fullpage-js-adding-a-scroll-delay). But I didn't get it how I can wait for a video to be loaded.

I'am thankful for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a video is loaded or not by attaching to it the 'load' event:

```js
document.querySelector('video').addEventListener('load', function(){
   //media is loaded
});
```

So you can use any logic there.