# How can i delay a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone assist me on how I can delay this function?

```
$('#customer_quote').lightbox_me({  
        centered: true, 
        closeSelect: ".close",
        onClose: function(){
            $('div.error').remove()
            }
        })  

 });
```

I want this lightbox to open after 7 seconds.

Comment: use setTimeout() http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/

Comment: Additional Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(lightbox, 7000);

function lightbox() {
    $('#customer_quote').lightbox_me({  
            centered: true, 
            closeSelect: ".close",
            onClose: function(){
                $('div.error').remove()
                }
            })  

     });
}
```

Comment: can you break down the code for me? so i know what happened? @Rory

Comment: The code is exactly the same as you had originally, the two differences are that I wrapped it in a function - `lightbox()` you can change this to be something more relevent if you need. The important part is the `setTimeout()`. You provide this method with a function to run, and the delay (in ms) defining when the function should be called.

Answer (score 4):

Give `setTimeout` a shot:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#customer_quote').lightbox_me({
        centered: true,
        closeSelect: ".close",
        onClose: function() {
            $('div.error').remove()
        }
    });
}, 7000);​
```

Answer (score 3):

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('#customer_quote').lightbox_me({  
        centered: true, 
        closeSelect: ".close",
        onClose: function(){
            $('div.error').remove()
            }
        })  

 });

}, 7000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this link out: [To delay JavaScript function call using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322344/to-delay-javascript-function-call-using-jquery)

Seems like you just use setTimeout with 7000

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout`.

```
var delayedFunction = function() {
   /* your code */
}

setTimeout(delayedFunction, 7000);
```

The second argument stands for the number of miliseconds.

Note also that this evokes an asynchronous event. The execution of your code will *not* stop at the line with `setTimeout` for 7 seconds.

If you want to execute another code after this delay, you must do so in `delayedFunction`, when the event fires.

Comment: This will keep calling `delayedFunction()` until `clearInterval()` is called. I do not think this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @siidhesh Sorry, I edited `setInterval` to `setTimeout` about a second after I posted the answer. I used it in my recent code more often, so consider that a typo :)